# How to check if my list already contains a certain string. Java Android SDK

Tags: java, android, list

I have a list:

```
List<String> oldfavs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have intialized

```
private TextView insult;
```

where

```
insult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insult);
```

and I want to be able to check if the string I am about to add is already in the list if it is in the List I don't want to add it:

Here's what I currently have:

```
public void SaveInsult(View view) {
    String saved = insult.getText().toString();
        if (oldfavs.contains(saved)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alreadyinfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            int listSize = oldfavs.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
            oldfavs.add(saved);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

However at the moment the string is always added even if the string is already in the list and I can't work out why or where I am going wrong.

Comment: the `insult` object doesn't seem to be intantiated or declared in the scope provided, Please post all the relevant code!

Comment: What is the purpose of that for loop? I'm not sure I understand the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `insult` and `oldfavs` are valid, and you only want to add the string if it's not in the list, and...do whatever `Toast.makeText(...)` does if the string isn't in the list, the following modifications should resolve your issue.

```
public void SaveInsult(View view) {
    String saved = insult.getText().toString();
        if (oldfavs.contains(saved)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alreadyinfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            oldfavs.add(saved);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: @James, I would urge you to consider using [sets in place of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32890093/5387814) for this purpose as it's less computationally expensive since you don't have to check for duplicates at all because of the definition of a set, plus it greatly improves readability of the code. Different design patterns and data structures were designed for these reasons!

Comment: @James for the record I agree with Andy, getting your datatype to work for you is almost always the right decision, and practicing the right way will make you a better developer.

Comment: I'll look into it, I'm pretty new to this, Thanks

Comment: @LanguidSquid with a set don't you need a key value pair, however I only have one element is the other automatically generated. Also is it possible to pass a HashSet to another activity and display it in a ListView?

Comment: @James I think you are thinking of a `Map` which requires a key, value pair. A `Set` does not. As far as I can tell, a `ListView` is strictly tied to the `List` interface, and is fundamentally incompatible with a `Set`, in order to make the `Set` work with a `ListView` you would need to manually convert the `Set` to a `List`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Set` rather than a `List` because a set doesn't contain duplicates, so you wouldn't need to perform any checks for duplicates:

```
List<String> oldfavsList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Allows duplicates when added
Set<String>  oldfavsSet  = new HashSet<String>();   // Duplicates are ignored when added
```

Comment: Thanks, @bigdestroyer, LanguidSquid has corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, contains() will check if the object instance passed is already on the array.

The problem is you are creating a new String instance, so it doesnt match with the String stored in the array.

Please someone correct me if im wrong.

Solution:

You can make a for loop and use String.compareTo() to find the matching string.

Example code:

```
for(int c=0;c<oldfavs.size();c++)
{
    if(oldfavs.get(c).compareTo(saved)==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alreadyinfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

That code will show your toast if the String is found properly.

Moreover, as pointed in the comments, i cant understand your for loop, it is adding the saved String the same number of times your arraylist size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: as stated in the javaDoc, the `.contains()` method already does this, it even calls `.equals()`! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object) So the loop is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own function to check if list contains particular string or not.

Follow the below code:

```
public void SaveInsult(View view) {
     String saved = insult.getText().toString();
    if (hasString(oldfavs )) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alreadyinfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        int listSize = oldfavs.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
        oldfavs.add(saved);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedfavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}
```

funtion:

```
public boolean hasString(List<String> list){

    boolean isPresent = false;
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){

        if(list.get(i).equals("Your String")){
            isPresent = true;
        }
    }

    return isPresent;
}
```

Comment: as stated in the javaDoc, the `.contains()` method already does this, it even calls `.equals()`! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)